# converting byte object to utf-8

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, byte

```
k = b'\xf2-\x92\xe7\x98\x90@\xddF\xbf\x13I4\x92\x0f\xc5'
```

I tried encoding in 'utf-8', but I am getting an error

```
utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

How can I properly convert this to a string  object?

Comment: You have to find out from the source how this byte sequence came to be. It's hard to guess stuff like this.

Comment: Any chance this is compressed?

Answer (score 0):

**#Update**
Ok I had to look at your byte it was the wrong encoding you need to use
ISO-8859-1

```
encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
k = b'\xf2-\x92\xe7\x98\x90@\xddF\xbf\x13I4\x92\x0f\xc5'.decode(encoding)
print(type(k))
```

That will fix the issue

Comment: Its a way to convert bytes to utf-8

Comment: The OP didnt list anything that he has done so this is the way that I have done it before

Comment: @MNM decoding this string with Latin-1 doesn't return anything useful. *Technically*, it's possible to decode any byte sequence with Latin-1 – it won't ever raise an exception. But in this case the output is simply a string of gibberish, not text, as you would expect from a text encoding.